# Save Count No of time records appear in the search results

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

We have a job portal where jobs are being posted by employers. We want to show the employer that how many times their job(s) appear in the search result.

Can you please let us know how save the statics about the jobs fetched using the following query:

```
SELECT Id, JobTitle,JobDescription 
FROM tblJobs 
WHERE JobTitle LIKE '%ASP.NET%'.
```

We are using `Sql Server 2008` and our application is in `ASP.NET/C#`

Answer (score 1):

Create a stats table with jobid and search counter columns.. 2 columns.

everytime you run the above search SQL query, get the job ids and increment the search counter.

to optimize you can just get the job ids in a table variable first, update the stats and then do a select to return the title etc.

```
UPDATE jobstats
SET searchcounter = searchcounter + 1

WHERE jobid IN
(
 jobids from above query
)
```